# Moving Average for multiple Columns with different window_size

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, moving-average

a large dataframe with multidimensional correlations, consisting of:

Date, Measurement 1, Measurement 2, ... Measurement 10, Variant

I have first calculated how often the variant occurs in the last two months using this function and then calculated the average.

```
def window_s_prüfpunkte(df, config_col, date_col, data_cols):
results = {}
for config in df[config_col].unique():
    config_df = df[df[config_col] == config]
    date_col = pd.to_datetime(config_df[date_col])
    monthly_count = config_df.groupby([date_col.dt.year, 
    date_col.dt.month]).count().rename_axis(['year', 'month'])[data_cols].reset_index()
    quantity_average = round(monthly_count[data_cols].mean().mean())
    results[config] = {'monthly_count': monthly_count,
                       'quantity_average': quantity_average}
return results

unique_configs = FSC3_Z_df_12M['Configuration Summary'].unique()
window_results = {}
for config in unique_configs:
   config_df = FSC3_Z_df_12M[FSC3_Z_df_12M['Configuration Summary'] == config]
   window_results[config] = window_s_prüfpunkte(config_df, 'Configuration Summary', 
   'Datum LP', COLS_Delta_Z)
```

Now I would like to calculate the moving average for each measurement by inserting the average value of the respective variant as the window size.

```
def moving_average_by_config(df, config_col, date_col, data_cols, window_results):
results = []
for config in df[config_col].unique():
    config_df = df[df[config_col] == config]
    config_window_size = window_results[config]
    for data_col in data_cols:
        config_df[f'{data_col}_MA'] = config_df[data_col].rolling(window=config_window_size).mean()
    results.append(config_df)
return pd.concat(results)
```

Unfortunately, this approach does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

```
# Create example dataframe
dates = pd.date_range('2022-01-01', '2022-02-28', freq='D')
variants = ['A', 'B', 'C']
data_cols = ['Measurement 1', 'Measurement 2', 'Measurement 3']
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': np.repeat(dates, len(variants) * len(data_cols)),
    'Variant': np.tile(np.repeat(variants, len(data_cols)), len(dates)),
    'Measurement 1': np.random.randn(len(dates) * len(variants) * len(data_cols)),
    'Measurement 2': np.random.randn(len(dates) * len(variants) * len(data_cols)),
    'Measurement 3': np.random.randn(len(dates) * len(variants) * len(data_cols))
})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

def window_s_prüfpunkte(df, config_col, date_col_name, data_cols):
    results = {}
    for config in df[config_col].unique():
        config_df = df[df[config_col] == config]
        date_col = pd.to_datetime(config_df[date_col_name])
        monthly_count = config_df.groupby([date_col.dt.year, 
        date_col.dt.month]).count().rename_axis(['year', 'month'])[data_cols].reset_index()
        quantity_average = round(monthly_count[data_cols].mean().mean())
        results[config] = {data_col: quantity_average for data_col in data_cols}
    return results


def moving_average_by_config(df, config_col, date_col, data_cols, window_sizes):
    results = []
    for config in df[config_col].unique():
        config_df = df[df[config_col] == config]
        for data_col in data_cols:
            config_window_size = window_sizes[config][data_col]
            config_df[f'{data_col}_MA'] = config_df[data_col].rolling(window=config_window_size).mean()
        results.append(config_df)
    return pd.concat(results)

window_sizes = window_s_prüfpunkte(df, 'Variant', 'Date', ['Measurement 1', 'Measurement 2', 'Measurement 3'])
moving_average_df = moving_average_by_config(df, 'Variant', 'Date', ['Measurement 1', 'Measurement 2', 'Measurement 3'], window_sizes)
```

The initial dataframe is

```
          Date Variant  Measurement 1  Measurement 2  Measurement 3
0   2022-01-01       A      -0.598400       0.186690       0.412284
1   2022-01-01       A       1.304156      -0.242278      -0.357972
2   2022-01-01       A      -0.689837      -0.583031       0.987450
3   2022-01-01       B       0.096719       1.300683       0.681955
4   2022-01-01       B      -0.034100      -0.540658       0.878540
..         ...     ...            ...            ...            ...
526 2022-02-28       B      -1.311980       0.702785       0.427267
527 2022-02-28       B      -1.322088      -1.358726      -0.429957
528 2022-02-28       C       0.753643      -0.811415       0.347925
529 2022-02-28       C       0.889842       0.086922      -1.129692
530 2022-02-28       C      -0.424379      -1.005491      -0.362359
```

and the ouput is

```
          Date Variant  Measurement 1  Measurement 2  Measurement 3  \
0   2022-01-01       A      -0.598400       0.186690       0.412284   
1   2022-01-01       A       1.304156      -0.242278      -0.357972   
2   2022-01-01       A      -0.689837      -0.583031       0.987450   
9   2022-01-02       A       0.640133      -1.602435       0.477864   
10  2022-01-02       A       0.489324      -0.585138       0.722814   
..         ...     ...            ...            ...            ...   
520 2022-02-27       C      -0.293254      -0.555126       0.414370   
521 2022-02-27       C      -0.428985       1.110329      -0.242367   
528 2022-02-28       C       0.753643      -0.811415       0.347925   
529 2022-02-28       C       0.889842       0.086922      -1.129692   
530 2022-02-28       C      -0.424379      -1.005491      -0.362359   

     Measurement 1_MA  Measurement 2_MA  Measurement 3_MA  
0                 NaN               NaN               NaN  
1                 NaN               NaN               NaN  
2                 NaN               NaN               NaN  
9                 NaN               NaN               NaN  
10                NaN               NaN               NaN  
..                ...               ...               ...  
520         -0.038969          0.105347          0.114437  
521         -0.044342          0.100342          0.115158  
528         -0.035779          0.089320          0.131298  
529         -0.017788          0.085785          0.103497  
530         -0.019763          0.059974          0.082724  

[531 rows x 8 columns]
```